# Searching for files using search.create in suitescript 2.0

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I'm searching for files using search.create but my search is returning every file within the folder including files within subfolders. I need only the files in a specific folder and not all files(files in subfolders).

Basically subfolder contents should not display in parent folder.

```
search.create({
     type: 'file',
     filters:
     [
        ['folder',"anyof", folderid]
     ],
   
     columns:
     [
        search.createColumn({
           name: "name",
           label: "Name",
           sort: search.Sort.ASC
          
        }),
        search.createColumn({
          name: "internalid",
          label: "ID",
          sort: search.Sort.ASC
         
       }),
     
   
       
     ]
  }).run();
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you cannot add an additional filter to the search that limits the files that belong only to that folder with no sub-folders. However, you can modify the search to search not the **file** record but **folder** record with joined files:

```
search.create({
     type: 'folder',
     filters:
     [
        ['internalid','is', folderId], 'AND',
        ['file.folder','is', folderId]
     ],
   
     columns:
     [
        search.createColumn({
           name: 'name',
           join: 'file'
        })
     ]
  }).run();
```

Not sure about the performance drawbacks of this approach but it might solve your issue. Please let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Search for a file by name in a folder

```
    search.create({
     type: 'folder',
     filters:
     [
        ['internalid','is', folderId], 'AND',
        ['file.name','is', fileName]
     ],
   
     columns:
     [
        search.createColumn({
           name: 'internalid',
           join: 'file'
        })
     ]
  }).run().getRange({
      start: 0,
      end: 10
    })
    .map(result => {
     console.log(result.getValue({ name: 'internalid', join: 'file' }))
    })
```